# Remove null values from json using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am trying to remove all the null values from my json.

```
{
   "key" : null
}
```

I have used:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Here "key" is a list and so when I use the above serialization option, the json gets converted to:

```
{
   "key" : []
}
```

I want the json to be:

```
{
}
```

I don't want to use

```
Include.NON_EMPTY
```

as I have other json in my project where I need to show the empty list and 0 valued keys. Is there any way to remove the null valued keys when it is a list, the same way it does for a string value?

I cannot use annotations as the class files are being generated from xml using jaxb. Class Structure:

```
public class C1 {

protected List<C2> key;

public List<C2> getKey() {
    if (key == null) {
        key = new ArrayList<C2>();
    }
    return this.key;
}

}
```

I have been stuck for a while now. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried by using annotations above the class. @user145078

Comment: in our production environment we use jaxb to convert xml to pojo so I don't have any control over the java files created and cannot use the annotations @VikrantKashyap

Comment: then you have write a custom NullSerializer to avoid that `key` in Serialized Object. @User

Comment: is there any documentation or examples I can take a look at to implement this? @VikrantKashyap

Comment: would you please post the `class` structure that you want to serialize. @user145078 becuase it wouldn't clear what exactly you trying to serialize .. Thanxx

Comment: I have updated the question with the class structure. thanks @VikrantKashyap

Answer (score 6):

To suppress serializing properties with `null` values,

you can configure the `ObjectMapper` directly using this.

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: that is what I have done. But for list values it converts null to []. I want to remove that key from the json itself. Is there a way to do that?